# No message available” error with Spring Boot , JAX-RS and angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

I have created project Spring Boot project and implemented Restful services as shown here:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Users")
public class UsersRestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser")
public Users addUsers( Users user){
    return UM.saveT(user);
}
}
```

AngularJS method :

```
Var url ="localhost:8080/App/Users";

$scope.saveUsers = function() {
$http.post(url+"/AddUser?name="+$scope.NameUser+"&email="+$scope.emailUser)
      .success(function(data) {
                $scope.ListUsers = data;
                $window.location.href="localhost:8080/App/AllUsers";
              }).error(function(err, data) {
                $scope.messag = "Add user error !!";
              });
}
```

Before doing the action of adding users, the administrator must authenticate to access my application. I made this configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
      protected void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
     //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER");
         auth.jdbcAuthentication()
             .dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, etat as actived from utilisateurs where username=?")
             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username as principal, ur.nom_role as role from utilisateurs u inner join roles ur on(u.roles_id=ur.id_role) where u.username=?")
             .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
     }

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
          .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(100).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).expiredUrl("/Login");
 http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/Users/").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")  
      .antMatchers("/Login").anonymous()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/Login").permitAll()
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
      .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")  
       .and()
         .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll() 
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/Login")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
         .csrf();
}
```

-class MvcConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
     DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
  }
}
```

I use the JSP framework for web pages, so I defied a controller to return JSP pages:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @RequestMapping( value = "/Login" )
    public String login(){
    return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/" )
    public String Home(){
    return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/Users" )
    public String Users(){
    return "indexUsers";
    }
```

-After authenticating the user I have all the list of users, but when you add a new user I get this problem:

> error:"Not Found" 
>   message:"No message available"
>   path:"/App/Users/AddUser" 
>   status:404 timestamp:1494256474299

Here the content of the request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/App/Users/AddUser?name=Michel&email=michel@gmail.com  

Request Method:POST

Status Code:404 

Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Request Headers

Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date:Mon, 08 May 2017 15:14:34 GMT

Expires:0

Pragma:no-cache

Transfer-Encoding:chunked

X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff

X-Frame-Options:DENY

X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.1

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:0

Cookie:JSESSIONID=671F3685C71CDEB58726FD1392389FA2

Host:localhost:8080

Origin:http://localhost:8080

Referer:http://localhost:8080/App/Users

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

**Query Strings Parameters:

name=Michel

email=michel@gmail.com
```

But when I do the Api Rest (http: // localhost: 8080 / Users / AddUser? Name=Michel&email=michel@gmail.com) the user will be added to the DB.

Can anyone help me find the missing point here?

Comment: In Angular method the URL mentioned is `url ="localhost:8080/App/Users"`. And the one you said working fine is `http://localhost:8080/Users/AddUser? Name=Michel&email=michel@gmail.com`. If so please remove `App` from angular base URL.

Comment: I apologize sir @Pete , the basic url is **http: //localhost:8080/App**

Comment: how did u test the API externally where you see the user get added?

Comment: I put the following url in the browser's address bar, ** http://localhost:8080/Users /AddUser? Name=Michel&email=michel@gmail.com**, and then I have the list of users containing the user I added (Michel)

Comment: Browser's address bar sends HTTP GET requests not POST. I see the your request mapping `@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser")` it will map all the request methods on `/AddUser`

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Pete the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

All Jax-RS methods are used by default ** Get **. Then we must define in the method angularjs the method Get also.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Users")
public class UsersRestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser")
public Users addUsers( Users user){
    return UM.saveT(user);
}
}
```

-Method angularJS:

```
$scope.saveUsers = function() {
    $http.get("URL_PATH")
          .success(function(data) {

            //Your code here
               })
    }
```